# automate .bat to get all content of a given directory

Tags: batch-file, filelist

I am trying to automate a process that stores all content (directories, sub-directories, files etc.) in a .txt file. I came up with this:

```
cd "D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy\"
dir /s /b>filelist.txt
```

When putting the above in a .bat file and running it manually, it works fine and creates the .txt file. However, when i include it in a Windows Scheduled task, it doesnt do anything. Can anyone help, getting this to work ?

Thanks!

Comment: `cd /d "D:...` should do.

Comment: thanks! this did the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to do it in two lines then you need to make sure you use the `/D` option, to change drives too:

```bat
CD /D "D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy"
Dir /S /B > "filelist.txt"
```

Alternatively you could use a single line without changing the current working directory:

```bat
Dir /S /B "D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy" > "filelist.txt"
```

Or with a different command:

```bat
Where /R "D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy" * > "filelist.txt"
```

Also you need to be aware that when run as a scheduled task, the working directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32` which is by default write protected, *(dependent upon permissions)*. Therefore the command will try to send its output to a file there unless you provide an accessible location:

```bat
> "C:\Users\kalinkula\Desktop\filelist.txt"
```

You could send the output to a file in the assessed directory, `D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy\filelist.txt`, as long as you don't mind that file appearing in it's own contained listing.

*These answers also assume that `D:` is mapped and/or available at the time the script/command is run.*

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just an FYI, but you could also do a structured output using `tree`

```
tree /f /a "D:\sources\SVN_WorkingCopy" > filelist.txt
```

which will result in the file structure to be something like:

```
D:.
├───e-shopper
│   └───Eshopper
|       └───temp folder
|           └───Performance Report Table.xlsx
|           └───Sales Document.docx
├───test Folder
│   └───Hire Freelancers
|       └───Performance Report Table.xlsx
|       └───Sales Document.docx
└───Some other Directory with no subs or files
```